# If ç sounds like a double s ("ss"), why was ç created?

Tags: etimologia, pronúncia, sinais-gráficos, homofonia

*Ç* is the only letter that was specifically placed on the Portuguese and Spanish keyboard as an independent key (French keyboard has ç, but not as an independent key).

The funny fact is that in Portuguese:

- *cassa* sounds like [**caça**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/ca%C3%A7a) - different from *casa* (that sounds like *caza*);
- *nassão* sounds like [**nação**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/na%C3%A7%C3%A3o);
- *pansa* sounds like [**pança**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pan%C3%A7a), notice that only one **s** is sufficient to express the **ss** sound when near the **n**: e.g. [pensa](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pensa) (*to think*)  ≠ pesa (*to weight*, with a **z** sound);
- *passo* sounds like [**paço**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pa%C3%A7o) and [passo](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/passo) already exists as a word.
- *possa* sounds like [**poça**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/po%C3%A7a) and [possa](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/possa) also exists already.
- *pessa* sounds like [**peça**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pe%C3%A7a).

So why was **ç** created?

Comment: If you guys are thinking of of following the french.SE pattern of closing cross language dupes (as we discussed on meta http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/36/perguntas-semelhantes-escritas-em-idiomas-distintos-devem-ser-consideradas-dup ), I think you should also take responsibility for translating answers (as Gilles said they do on french.SE). Personally, I prefer the german.SE approach (leaving them open).

Comment: The funny thing is that it was already decided that duplicates in another language wouldn't be considered duplicates. But it seems like they changed their mind..

Comment: * "pansa sounds like pança" one "s" only

Comment: Voted to reopen: **either** 1. add translations to the other question and keep this one closed as dup, or 2. allow this one to be open but linked to the other question. Meta discussion: http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/36/perguntas-semelhantes-escritas-em-idiomas-distintos-devem-ser-consideradas-dup

Comment: @JorgeB. nice catch! Edited just now. Thanks!

Comment: @ANeves Translation into English added to the other question’s question and answer alike. This question is therefore a clear duplicate.